# Query by foreign key value instead of left join

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, spring-data

I have a relation 1-n between two tables (let's call them User and Roles):

```
User(ID, Name, LastName, ...)
Role(ID, User_ID, Label, ...) where User_ID is a foreign key to reference the User
```

In my Role repository, I have a method like this:

```
public List<Role> findByUser(User user);
```

The generated SQL is of the following form:

```
select ... from Role r left outer join User u on u.ID = r.User_ID where u.ID = ?
```

This is a performance botleneck. How to make spring-data generate a simpler query, like:

```
select ... from Role r where r.User_ID = ?
```

(get rid of the useless join)

Comment: `@Query("select r from Role r where r.user = :user")`

Comment: possible without @Query? using a method name convention or something?

Answer (score 1):

Can't check it now but you can try the following:

```
public List<Role> findByUser_ID(Long id);
```

or

```
public List<Role> findBy_User_ID(Long id);
```

It may also depend on JPA implementation and mapping. ID should be properly mapped as primary keys and User_ID as a foreign key. Lazy loading for Role.user may also affect.